# How do I use a regular expression to match a name?

Tags: python, regex

I am a newbie in Python. I want to write a regular expression for some name checking.
My input string can contain a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and ' _ ', but it should start with either a-z or A-Z (not 0-9 and ' _ '). I want to write a regular expression for this.  I tried, but nothing was matching perfectly.

Once the input string follows the regular expression rules, I can proceed further, otherwise discard that string.

Comment: Is the empty string to be allowed?

Comment: empty string cannot be allowed. "_" this is hypen not dash

Comment: "_" is underscore, not hyphen.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an answer to your question:

Interpreting that you want `_` (not `-`), this should do the job:

```
>>> tests = ["a", "A", "a1", "a_1", "1a", "_a", "a\n", "", "z_"]
>>> for test in tests:
...    print repr(test), bool(re.match(r"[A-Za-z]\w*\Z", test))
...
'a' True
'A' True
'a1' True
'a_1' True
'1a' False
'_a' False
'a\n' False
'' False
'z_' True
>>>
```

Stoutly resist the temptation to use `$`; here's why:

**Hello, hello, using `$` is WRONG, use `\Z` instead**

```
>>> re.match(r"[a-zA-Z][\w-]*$","A")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00BAFE90>
>>> re.match(r"[a-zA-Z][\w-]*$","A\n")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00BAFF70> # WRONG; SHOULDN'T MATCH
>>>

>>> re.match(r"[a-zA-Z][\w-]*\Z","A")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00BAFE90>
>>> re.match(r"[a-zA-Z][\w-]*\Z","A\n")
>>> # CORRECT: NO MATCH
```

[The Fine Manual](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) says:

'$'
    Matches the end of the string **or just before the newline at the end of the string** [my emphasis], and in MULTILINE mode also matches before a newline. foo matches both ‘foo’ and ‘foobar’, while the regular expression foo$ matches only ‘foo’. More interestingly, searching for foo.$ in 'foo1\nfoo2\n' matches ‘foo2’ normally, but ‘foo1’ in MULTILINE mode; searching for a single $ in 'foo\n' will find two (empty) matches: one just before the newline, and one at the end of the string.

and

\Z
    Matches only at the end of the string.

=== And now for something completely different ===

```
>>> import string
>>> letters = set(string.ascii_letters)
>>> ok_chars = letters | set(string.digits + "_")
>>>
>>> def is_valid_name(strg):
...     return strg and strg[0] in letters and all(c in ok_chars for c in strg)
...
>>> for test in tests:
...     print repr(test), repr(is_valid_name(test))
...
'a' True
'A' True
'a1' True
'a_1' True
'1a' False
'_a' False
'a\n' False
'' ''
'z_' True
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import re

>>> re.match("[a-zA-Z][\w-]*$","A")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00932E20>

>>> re.match("[a-zA-Z][\w-]*$","A_B")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x008CA950>

>>> re.match("[a-zA-Z][\w-]*$","0A")
>>> 
>>> re.match("[a-zA-Z][\w-]*$","!A_B")
>>>
```

**Note**: OP mentioned `string cannot start from ( 0-9 and "_").`, apparently _ can be in the text. Thats why I am using `\w`

**Note2**: If you don't want match string ends with `\n`, you could use `\Z` instead of `$` as John Machin mentioned.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z][\w-]*$`
This regex is wrong as it will match a string that starts with anything. Almost there though, just needs a circumflex at the beginning.

Comment: @Mikuso, `re.match()` only matches from the start of the string. `re.search()` would need the caret

Comment: IF? If you do consciously want to match a "name" that ends with "\n", seek help.

Answer (score -1):

here's a non re way

```
import string
flag=0
mystring="abcadsf123"
if not mystring[0] in string.digits+"_":
    for c in mystring:
       if not c in string.letters+string.digits+"-":
           flag=1
    if flag: print "%s not ok" % mystring
    else: print "%s ok" % mystring
else: print "%s starts with digits or _" % mystring
```

Comment: (1) The questioner didn't say he wanted locale-dependent results; he said he wanted [a-zA-Z], so use string.ascii_letters (2) crashes if input is "" (3) the flag thing is horrid